# Trying to create bottom tab from scratch

Tags: react-native, image, tabs, navigation, touch

I was trying to create a bottom tab with my own custom images, but I am stuck where it is impossible to move on because when I use touchableOpacity on multiple images it either doesn't work or some images disappears in the process how can I tacle this problem better. [image of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfeKY.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfeKY.png) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhyiE.png

sorry for not providing more details

Thanks for replying, I was trying to create the bottom tab like user profile, home setting and many more using my own icons, for example if I press on a picture Icon of a user it should take me to a user profile page something like the below[here a how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfeKY.png) picture

Now I have no problem with navigation but only trouble with image and touchable. Here's the full code
of that page

```
enter code here

enter code here

const hereUserHome = () => {

  const Stack = createDrawerNavigator()
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  const profileName = "Home"
  const chatName = "Chat"
  const VideoChatName = "VideoChats"
  const VideosName = "Videos"
  const MusicName = "Musics"

  return (

    <View style = {UserHomeStyles.bgd}>
          <View ><SignOutUser/></View>

        <TouchableOpacity>
        <View onPress={() => {goToNextPage()}}>
              <Image
                animation = {"flipInY"}
                duration={1800}
                source={require("../../components/logo/user.png")}
                style = {UserHomeStyles.logo_profile}
                resizeMode = "contain"
              />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>  
        
          
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image
              animation = {"flipInY"}
              duration={1800}
              source={require("../../components/logo/chat1.png")}
              style = {UserHomeStyles.logo_chat}
              resizeMode = "contain"
            />

            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>


          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image
                animation = {"flipInY"}
                duration={1800}
                source={require("../../components/logo/video_chat.png")}
                style = {UserHomeStyles.logo_video_chat}
                resizeMode = "contain"
            /> 
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image
                animation = {"flipInY"}
                duration={1800}
                source={require("../../components/logo/video_beast1.png")}
                style = {UserHomeStyles.logo_video_beast}`enter code here`
                resizeMode = "contain"
            />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image
                animation = {"flipInY"}
                duration={1800}
                source={require("../../components/logo/music.png")}
                style = {UserHomeStyles.logo_music_beast}
                resizeMode = "contain"
            />  
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

        </View> 
  )
}

export default UserHome
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to create is a custom bottom tab navigator. You have used your createBottomTabNavigator in your code. I'll drop an example code to get you an idea. Here you can replace the icons with your custom images.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BottomTabNavigationOptions, createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import Foundation from 'react-native-vector-icons/Foundation';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import Discovery from '@src/modules/discovery/screens/Discovery';
import CreatePost from '@src/modules/createPost/CreatePost';
import Notifications from '@src/modules/notifications/Notifications';
import Profile from '@src/modules/profile/screens/Profile';

import HomeStackNavigator from './HomeStackNavigator';

const tabBarOptions: BottomTabNavigationOptions = {
  headerShown: false,
  tabBarAllowFontScaling: false,
  tabBarLabelPosition: 'below-icon',
  tabBarActiveTintColor: '#000',
  tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
  tabBarShowLabel: false,
};

const MainTabNavigator: React.FC = () => {
  const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator();

  return (
    <TabStack.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }): BottomTabNavigationOptions => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }): React.ReactNode => {
          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            return <Foundation name="home" size={size} color={color} />;
          }
          if (route.name === 'Discovery') {
            return <Feather name="search" size={size} color={color} />;
          }
          if (route.name === 'Post') {
            return <Feather name="plus-square" size={size} color={color} />;
          }
          if (route.name === 'Notifications') {
            return <AntDesign name="hearto" size={size} color={color} />;
          }
          if (route.name === 'Profile') {
            return <Ionicons name="person-outline" size={size} color={color} />;
          }
          return <></>;
        },
        ...tabBarOptions,
      })}>
      <TabStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackNavigator} />
      <TabStack.Screen name="Discovery" component={Discovery} />
      <TabStack.Screen name="Post" component={CreatePost} />
      <TabStack.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
      <TabStack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
    </TabStack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default MainTabNavigator;
```